# Is it safe to pass validation result directly to new object

Tags: laravel, validation, security, code-injection, laravel-6

I have set up the following Request class to validate my input:

```
.
.
.
class SupplierStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    .
    .
    .
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ];
    }

}
```

And I have the following method in my controller:

```
public function store(SupplierStoreRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $supplier = new Supplier($validated);
    $supplier->save();
    return redirect()->route('Admin::supplier.index');
}
```

Which works exactly as expected. My question is:

**Is there a risk of SQL or JavaScript injection, or any other security risks in this code or does the FormRequest class take care of that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR Prepared statements through Eloquent and escaping with `htmlspecialchars` through blade variables is how you prevent SQL injections and JavaScript injections. Validation is just for checking if the user input is in the expected format (which can even be JavasScript or SQL on purpose).**

If you use Eloquent (without `raw`) you use prepared statements, which help prevent SQL injections. Validation is not a part of this process and only is in place to check the validity of the input, not for attacks per se.

> Laravel's database query builder provides a convenient, fluent
>   interface to creating and running database queries. It can be used to
>   perform most database operations in your application and works on all
>   supported database systems.
>
> The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your
>   application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean
>   strings being passed as bindings.

As for JavaScript injection, the same thing applies when using `{{ $var }}` statements in Blade files. You should not rely on validation for preventing attacks solely. It's really, really, really hard to prevent all forms of attack by validation.

> Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's
>   htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data

Comment: I've accepted your answer. But to be clear you are basically saying the code is fine, but not because of the validation. If this is the case then it might be useful if you stated this directly in your answer